# Applied for an internal position - too forward to email hiring manager?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, email

I currently have a job for which I have received performance awards. My same job--same duties and responsibilities--opened up in the same company, but in my hometown city. I am anxious to go back to my hometown, so I really want that job. I would imagine my chances are high, but I don't want to put my hopes up. Anyway, since I work in the same company, I was able to find the email address of the hiring manager. Right after I applied I emailed him to indirectly express my interest in the job by asking him questions about the projects they do, answers to which I couldn't find myself. He responded to that email by basically saying thanks for the interest and providing the answer to my question.

Now, I will be in my hometown for vacation next week. I took a few working days off, so I would be available for an in-person interview, should they consider my application (which I'm sure they will). The position closed this past Thursday. I thought about sending the hiring manager another email this coming Friday to re-express my interest in the position and indicate that if my application is considered, I would be available for an in-person interview while I'm in my hometown. The thing is, I currently live an 8-hour drive away from my hometown, so if not for those dates, I would have to do a phone interview (which I don't like).

Would it hurt my candidacy if I were to email him about my interview availability? Would it be too presumptuous? Note: HR is not involved in the hiring process at my company. The hiring manager oversees the entire process, so I can only contact him about the position.

One option is to email him to check on the status of the app, and if he responds, tell him that I will be available for an in-person interview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had an out of town candidate who was going to be in town on a set date that was close enough to when I was doing interviewing, I would want to know about it.

HR is another possibility to contact.  They may be doing the intial interviews and scheduling, so letting them know of your in-town availability would also be something to consider.

Comment: HLGEM-thanks for your response. Again, HR does not do the scheduling/initial interviews. It all starts and ends with this hiring manager. I actually met him at a conference this week and plan on sending this follow-up email on Monday. Could you please tell me how it sounds? see below comment...

Comment: Hello Mr. X,

It was a pleasure to meet you and A at the conference. I want to reiterate my interest in the X position and feel it would be a great match with my educational background and experience.  I don’t know of your timeline for the position, though I want to inform you I will be in X City to visit family this week. If my application is being considered, I will be available for an in-person interview Tuesday-Thursday. However, if you have already moved forward with the position, then I can understand. 

Thank you for considering me, and all the best!

john

Answer (score 2):

> Would it hurt my candidacy if I were to email him about my interview
>   availability? Would it be too presumptuous?

Not too presumptuous at all. However, I have an even better idea. Call him up, let him know you'll be in town, and you'd like to buy him lunch.

It may be that because HR closed the opening, the position is filled and it's no longer a possibility, but your chances of moving back to you home-town and still work for this company apparently begin and end with this one individual. It's in *your* best interests to get to know him better than you do. And buying him lunch is an easy way to try. (And who says no to a free lunch?)